# How to create and store a SHA2-512 hash with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I tried to look for a SHA2-512 hashing function in PHP, but did not see one. For a project I am currently working on, I need to allow a user to reset their password. When they do so, I would like to hash the password using SHA2-512 in the PHP script, and then store it in the database with their associated username. I am already getting the username and password from the HTML form, so that is not an issue. I just can't seem to figure out how to use `hash()` or `openssl_digest()` to hash the password using SHA2-512 (I am using PHP 5). Also, would I just store the hexadecimal hash in my database as a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: `hash("sha512", plain_password)` this will generate hashed password

Comment: Have you tried googling "php sha512"? [This is the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I thought that was SHA1?

Comment: @Pharaoh I have, and I was under the impression those are SHA1

Comment: Quote: ***algo**: Name of selected hashing algorithm (e.g. "md5", "sha256", "haval160,4", etc..)*

Comment: Please use the built-in [password API](http://php.net/password) for this kind of thing.

Comment: @JonStirling thanks! I was not even aware that existed. Most of the tutorials and examples just use the crypto hashing functions. I wish one had used the password hash!

Comment: If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @lillemap yes, it's confusing, but they actually belong to the SHA2 family, here are some official docs https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/sp/800/131/a/r2/final - and this PDF https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-131Ar2.pdf mentions: "SHA-2 family (SHA-
224, SHA-256,
SHA-384, SHA-512,
SHA-512/224 and
SHA-512/256)", "SHA-3 family
(SHA3-224, SHA3-256, SHA3-384, and
SHA3-512)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal identifiers make your tables and indexes bigger and slow down comparisons. I suggest you to do not use it but if you must use hexadecimal values for identifier you can make it binary.

You can hash like that;

```
$hashed_password = hash('sha512', $password);
```

Comment: I am trying to write a query like: `$set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('admin', ";
 $hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $set_login = $set_login . $hash . ")"` but it does not seem to work

Comment: Try this; $hash = hash("sha512", $password);
        $set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('admin', ";      $var1="'";  $var2="'";   $var3=")";
        $querry = $set_login.$var1.$hash.$var2.$var3;

Comment: I simplified my code to: `$u = "admin";
 $hash = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $set_login = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ($u, $hash)";` and it still is not working

Comment: password_hash function  takes three parameter. string password_hash ( string $password , integer $algo [, array $options ] ) . You can see documentation in this  [link](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: The third is optional. It will generate a salt automatically if not given one

Comment: what is the error message? can you try to hash with hash('sha512',$password) so we can understand whether password_hash working or not

Comment: How would I get the error message? I'm on a shared server that does not have a PHP error log.

Comment: Like that; mysql_query($query); echo mysql_error();

Comment: your querry seems okay, can you make sure your database fields name match with the querry ?